# Center only one value of a table

Tags: tables

Any way to center "ID" on the table below?

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|}
\hline
             \centering{ID}          & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{RM1}}                      \\ \hline
                                     & $\Delta G^\circ_{cosmo}$ & $\Delta G^\circ_{cosmo-SS}$ \\ \hline
CCref                                &                          &                             \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

I tried `\centering{ID}` but it doesn't work. 
 Also tried `\centerline` but doesn't work.

Comment: Just use `\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{ID}`

Comment: also `_{cosmo}` should be `_{\textrm{cosmo}}`

Comment: @Mico good. Post it as an answer, or I can remove the question if it is too stupid

Comment: @DavidCarlisle oh you are right, thanks. I must change all the tables. I will try with ctrl H

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you write

```
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{ID}
```

By the way, `\centering` is a switch and doesn't take an argument.

A full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for appropriate sizing of \textrm
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{ID} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{RM1}}                      \\ 
\hline
       & $\Delta G^\circ_{\textrm{cosmo}}$ % per David C.'s suggestion
       & $\Delta G^\circ_{\textrm{cosmo-SS}}$ \\ \hline
CCref  &  &  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: great, thanks Mico. I will accept in 6 minutes ;)